# How can I act on the results of the "locate" command?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line, grep, locate

I'm trying to find where `check_dns` is defined in `nagios`' `commands.cfg` file, although there are quite a few files.

I know I could run something like `find / -name "command.cfg" -exec grep check_dns {} \;` to search for matches, but if possible I would like to use `locate` since it is an indexed copy and much faster.

When I run `locate commands.cfg` I get the following results:

```
/etc/nagios3/commands.cfg
/etc/nagiosgrapher/nagios3/commands.cfg
/usr/share/doc/nagios3-common/examples/commands.cfg
/usr/share/doc/nagios3-common/examples/template-object/commands.cfg
/usr/share/nagiosgrapher/debian/cfg/nagios3/commands.cfg
/var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:nagiosgrapher:nagios3:commands.cfg
```

Is it possible to run locate and pipe it to an inline command like `xargs` or something so that I can `grep` each of the results? I realize this can be done with a for loop but I'm looking to pick up some bash-fu / shell-fu here more than how to do it for this specific case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use `xargs` for this.

For example a simple:

```
$ locate commands.cfg | xargs grep check_dns
```

(When `grep` sees multiple files it searches in each one and enables filename printing along matches.)

Or you can explicitly enable filename printing via:

```
$ locate commands.cfg | xargs grep -H check_dns
```

(Just in case one `grep` is called only with 1 argument by `xargs`)

For programs that only accept one filename argument (unlike `grep`) you can restrict the number of supplied arguments like this:

```
$ locate commands.cfg | xargs -n1 grep check_dns
```

That does not print the names of files where matched lines are from.

The result is equivalent to:

```
$ locate commands.cfg | xargs grep -h check_dns
```

With a modern locate/xargs you can also protect against whitespace issues:

```
$ locate -0 commands.cfg | xargs -0 grep -H check_dns
```

(By default whitespace separates input of `xargs` - which is of course a problem when your filenames contain whitespace ...)

Comment: well that's all easy and simple enough! :) thank you!

Comment: Nice. simple. Effective.