# Quick way to open results from `find` or `locate`

Tags: bash, find, locate

When I run `find` or `locate`, the matching files will populate stdout, one file per line. The next step is often that I want to open one of these files. This would be faster and more efficient if I did not have to type out the entire file path, but simply could interact with the search results somehow. Which is the fastest way to open a file displayed in the search results?

Solutions like those given in [Open a result of `locate` with `vi`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189704/open-a-result-of-locate-with-vi), [How to `locate` multiple files and open them in vim?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45782/how-to-locate-multiple-files-and-open-them-in-vim?rq=1), and  [How can I act on the results of the "locate" command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35073/how-can-i-act-on-the-results-of-the-locate-command?rq=1) require typing out a rather long second command, which is not as fast as I would like.

Instead, is there a way to, for example, automatically assign each file from the search result to a numerical variable name (s1 - sn), so that to open the first result I would simply type `vi $s1`? Or is a better solution to this problem to use a fuzzy finder like [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) or [fasd](https://github.com/clvv/fasd)?

Comment: How many files are you expecting to be found? `find ... -exec vim {} +` may well open all the files in a single instance of `vim`, and work regardless of what characters (*including* newlines) may appear in the file names.

Comment: Similar: [Bash: Capture / Use last (or Nth) line in stdout](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/59700)

Comment: @chepner I read about the `-exec` flag to `find` , but I would ideally use a solution that works with `locate` as well.

Answer (score 6):

I've had this in my `~/.screenrc` for a while:

```
bind -c pasteline 1 eval copy 'stuff "-Y"' 'paste .'
bind -c pasteline 2 eval copy 'stuff "2-Y"' 'paste .'
bind -c pasteline 3 eval copy 'stuff "3-Y"' 'paste .'
bind -c pasteline 4 eval copy 'stuff "4-Y"' 'paste .'
bind -c pasteline 5 eval copy 'stuff "5-Y"' 'paste .'
bind -c pasteline 6 eval copy 'stuff "6-Y"' 'paste .'
bind -c pasteline 7 eval copy 'stuff "7-Y"' 'paste .'
bind -c pasteline 8 eval copy 'stuff "8-Y"' 'paste .'
bind -c pasteline 9 eval copy 'stuff "9-Y"' 'paste .'
bindkey ¬ command -c pasteline
```

Basically, typing <kbd>¬</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> from within screen, inserts the first line above the cursor, <kbd>¬</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> the second line and so on.

In my `~/.Xdefaults`, I also have:

```
XTerm.VT100.translations:             #override\
    Meta <KeyPress> /: dabbrev-expand()
```

Which lets `xterm` complete (upon <kbd>Alt+/</kbd>) on what's on the screen (looking backward from the cursor position).

With `zsh`, when used within `screen`, you could do:

```
copy-screen() {
  screen -X eval copy 'stuff "-$ H\r"' 'writebuf .lastoutput'
  killring=(${(Oaf)"$(<~/.lastoutput)"})
  CUTBUFFER=$killring[1]
  killring[1]=()
}
zle -N copy-screen
bindkey '\ec' copy-screen
```

to bind <kbd>Alt+C</kbd> to that widget that stores the lines above the cursor into the cut buffer and the kill ring (what you paste with <kbd>Ctrl+Y</kbd> and cycle through with <kbd>Alt+Y</kbd> in `emacs` mode). (the above assumes `screen` was started from your home directory).

If the inserted text needs to be quoted (because it contains spaces or other special shell characters for instance), you can type <kbd>Alt+"</kbd> for `zsh` to quote it.

As an example, you've just run:

```
$ find /usr/local -size +1M
/usr/local/lib/liblzma.a
/usr/local/share/doc/sudo/ChangeLog
/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Unicode/Unihan/Definition.db
/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Unicode/Unihan/RSKangXi.db
/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Unicode/Unihan/IRG_TSource.db
/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Unicode/Unihan/HanYu.db
/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Unicode/Unihan/RSUnicode.db
/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Unicode/Unihan/IRG_GSource.db
/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Unicode/Unihan/IRGKangXi.db
/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Unicode/Unihan/IRGHanyuDaZidian.db
```

And you want to open `vim` on that sudo ChangeLog above. With the first approach you'd type:

```
vim ¬9
```

With the second approach:

```
vim /usAlt+/
```

And repeat that <kbd>Alt+/</kbd> until you get to the changelog.

With the third approach:

```
vim Alt+CCtrl+YAlt+Y
```

And repeat that <kbd>Alt+Y</kbd> until you get to the changelog.

The last approach can be used for your `$s1` query.

Instead of storing in the `killring` array, store in an array (like `$s`) and use `$s[1]` for the first line, `$s[2]` for the second...

```
copy-screen() {
  screen -X eval copy 'stuff "-$ H\r"' 'writebuf .lastoutput'
  s=(${(Oaf)"$(<~/.lastoutput)"})
}
zle -N copy-screen
bindkey '\ec' copy-screen
```

That <kbd>Alt+C</kbd> stores the lines above the cursor in the `s` array.

In any case, what we're retrieving is what is displayed on the screen, which is not necessarily the same as what the last command output. For instance `printf 'a\bc \n'` outputs 5 bytes `a`, BS, `c`, SPC and LF, but displays just a `c`.

Comment: Great! Thank you for this detailed answer! I am not using screen myself, but you inspired my solution using `tmux`. I also found this [tmux plugin](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-copycat) that seems to perform a similar function although I prefer the simpler solution I have already.

Answer (score 4):

With `bash`:

```
IFS=$'\n' select fname in $(locate fubar); do
    if [ "$fname" ]; then
        vim "$fname"
        break
    fi
done
```

With Vim:

```
!!locate fubar
```

-- then go to the file you want and press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>.  See also `:h gf` and `:h 'isfname'`.

Another way with Vim: see `:h :find`.  With recent versions of Vim see `:h :filter`.

Yet another way with Vim: use the [Unite](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim) plugin.  Or, for `grep`-like operations, use the [CtrlSF](https://github.com/dyng/ctrlsf.vim) plugin.  There are, of course, many other ways.

Answer (score 4):

If you can bear with the ugliness of the Bash arrays, you could do something like

```
mapfile res < <(find -name <pattern>)
```

or

```
mapfile res < <(locate <pattern>)
```

This will save your lines into an array `res`.

Then you can see the matches and iterate through them:

```
$ echo "${res[@]}" # lists all matches
$ editor ${res[2]} # opens the third match
```

PS

I just use the mouse to select the line I need, though. Or just do

```
$ editor `locate <pattern>`
```

if I know there aren't many results or "fancy" characters.

Answer (score 1):

I combined ideas Sato Katsura's and Stéphane Chazelas's answers into a script, which is aliased to `sr` (for "Select Result"). It can be called after a command that outputs paths line by line to stdout. For example

```
$ locate genomics
/home/user/articles/macaulay_voet_2014_plos_genetics.pdf
/home/user/articles/shmulevich_et_al_2003_comparative_functional_genomics.pdf

$ sr zh
1) /home/user/articles/macaulay_voet_2014_plos_genetics.pdf
2) /home/user/articles/shmulevich_et_al_2003_comparative_functional_genomics.pdf
#?
```

The script then waits for me to type a number and press enter, after which it opens that item in the program specified as the first argument (in this case zathura, for which I have defined the shorthand `zh` in the script). I have yet to test this extensively, but it is doing everything I want at the moment.

My current solution requires `tmux`, since it can access the output of the last command without rerunning it (by copying from the terminal). Similar solutions exist for `screen` as shown in Stéphane Chazelas' answer. If using neither of these, one could simply get the last command from history and then evaluate it again in the `select` statement. Below is the full script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Enumerate stdout from the previous search command line by line.
# Enable opening a file by passing the desired opening program as an
# argument and then select a number from the output.
# Defaults to using `xdg-open` when no argument is passed.
# Does only work for stdout that list the full path to a file or relative
# the directory this script is being called from.

# Aliases are not expanded within bash scripts.
# Create a few aliases instead of importing entire alias file.
case $1 in
    '' )
        opener='xdg-open'
        ;;
    'vi' )
        opener='nvim'
        ;;
    'zh' )
        opener='zathura'
        ;;
    * )
        opener=$1
esac

# The default split delimiter in bash is any whitespace. Change this
# to only split on newline in order to account for filenames with spaces.
old_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'

# Use tmux to copy the paragraph above. This specific navigation sequence
# only works if each prompt is prefaced with a newline, such as from having
# `precmd() { print "" }` in `.zshrc`
tmux copy-mode
tmux send-keys 2 { 3 j 0 space } enter
# Results are saved in an array for clarity
search_results+=$(tmux save-buffer -)
select fname in $search_results; do
    $opener "$fname"
    break
done

# Set IFS back to default
IFS="$old_IFS"
```

Comment: The point of `if [ "$fname" ]` is to test that `fname` is set and not empty.  Historically you had to write that as `if [ x"$fname" != x ]`, but modern shells allow `if [ "$fname" ]`.  However, `if [ '"$fname"' ]` is wrong (it's always true).  The nested `if` is also better written as a `case`. :)

Comment: @SatoKatsura Thanks for the tips! I updated the answer accordingly. I don't think `$fname` will ever be empty since I am choosing from a list visually, but correct me if I am wrong there.

Comment: The empty `$fname` happens when you choose the wrong number, or when you just press Enter.  It's pretty much a safety net.

Answer (score 0):

One method comes to mind. You could use the full-screen editor specified by 'EDITOR' in your shell environment. The editor is started by pressing `^X^E` (ctrl-x, ctrl-e). From within the editor (such as vim) you could run:

```
:r!find /
```

The results of this would be imported, you can then trim the output to what you wish, when you write and exit, the contents would be run as a command, as if you entered it at the shell prompt.